# Diffeomorphism with non-differentiable inverse

Tags: differential-geometry

Spivak defines a diffeomorphism over manifolds $f:(M,A)\to (N,B)$ as a mapping such that $x\in B$ if and only if $x\circ f\in A$.

Next, he states that $f(x)=x^3$ is a diffeormophism between $(\mathbb{R},U)$  and $(\mathbb{R},V)$ where $U$ is the usual structure and $V$ is the maximal atlas that contains the homeomorphism $x\to x^3$. That is because $x\in U$ if and only if $x\circ f\in V$

However, he later states that a differentiable function is a diffeomorphism if and only if its inverse is differentiable.

I fail to see why this would hold, more so since $f$ is an obvious counter-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse $f^{-1}:({\Bbb R},V)\longrightarrow({\Bbb R},U)$ is differentiable. $f^{-1}:({\Bbb R},U)\longrightarrow({\Bbb R},U)$ isn't.

Comment: Umm, I see... That's what I missed. Thanks. (I guess I'll drop this book for now, I'm just not fit for it yet.)